# Using XML prefixes/namespaces to create an Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

This is a follow on from my [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728581/retrieving-xml-values-from-namespace-elements-with-php). I think I jumped in at the deep end so spending some time fully understanding XML namespaces.

From [this](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/XmlView.aspx?data=yieldyear&year=2015) XML page, gonna focus on the below element for a min:

```
<m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
```

I understand that the `m:` prefix has been used in order to distinguish the `properties` element from elements with the same name in other documents, in case such documents are combined.
I understand that in order to use a prefix, a namespace for that prefix must be defined. Such a definition is done using the XML namespace attribute (xmlns) and the syntax is `xmlns:prefix="URI"`. URI is the [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192022/parsing-xml-with-namespaces-in-sql-server), which is basically the element's source. URIs used to be called [Uniform Resource Names (URN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name), which are essentially the same thing.

Now taking a look at the answer to my prior Q:

```
$url = "http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/XmlView.aspx?data=yieldyear&year=2015";
$element = simplexml_load_file($url);

$element->registerXPathNamespace(
  'atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
);
$element->registerXpathNamespace(
  'meta', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservice/metadata'
);

foreach ($element->xpath('//atom:entry/atom:content/meta:properties') as $properties) {
  $properties->registerXpathNamespace('data', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices');
  echo $properties->xpath('data:Id')[0], "\n";
  echo $properties->xpath('data:NEW_DATE')[0], "\n\n";
}
```

*XPath is a syntax for defining parts of an XML document. The `registerXPathNamespace()` function creates a prefix for a specified namespace.*

It makes sense to me why the `atom` prefix was created using `registerXPathNamespace()` for `<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">` in order to reference it like this `//atom:entry/atom:content/meta:properties` because the entry tag doesn't use a prefix.

Why was the `meta` prefix created? There was already an `m:` prefix with the same namespace defined.

Would using the below have done the same thing?

```
//atom:entry/atom:content/m:properties
```

Unfortunately, I don't have access to my server until later today. I'll test it myself then. If it doesn't work, more interested in why not, logic would suggest it should?

Comment: Next question in my series on XML namespaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771883/name-sql-table-rows-to-match-xml-namespace-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `m:` prefix was bound in the XML instance, but your XPath processor doesn't know that. It needs the prefix bound (registered) separately.

The `meta:` prefix is arbitrary. It could've been `m:` just like the XML, but it doesn't matter. As long as the URI is the same. The `atom:` prefix could've been `a:` and it would still work.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! How is your SQL? :) is this xPath approach the same if I was to try and match elements up with MySQL table rows? Have another Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771883/name-sql-table-rows-to-match-xml-namespace-elements

Comment: Sorry @Pete my SQL experience is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this would help you.Best guide on namespace that I found on the net.

https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~xing/Lib/NamespacesFAQ.htm#q8_5